# oracle plsql: return table line by line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am tasked to return a query result using a stored plsql procedure involving multiple tables. currently, I wrote code something like this:

```
create or replace function sample(userinput varchar) return varchar2 is
c_list varchar2(1000) // this line keep triggers a too small string buffer error
begin
for c in (
  select name, id, count(*)
  from temp join temp2 on temp.id = temp2.id
  where data = userinput)
loop
c_list := c_list || c.name || c.id || '';
end loop;
end;
/
```

```
select name, sample(name)
from temp join temp2 ...
```

Every time I try i get either the function error or too small string buffer error, and not rly sure if this is the right approach.

Can someone help me to figure out this?

Comment: What form are you expected to return the query result in? Who/what will call the function and what will they expect the result to look like, and how will they process it? From the very vague description of the requirement you might want to return a ref cursor, but it's hard to tell. Are you only expecting a single string result? (Your query also doesn't have a group-by...)

Comment: @Alex Poole hi, i hv to write a function that returns a single line query result, so that when it is called the result would look like a table. I tried to use cursor too but im quiet a newbie here so not rly sure of anything:/

Comment: How can a single line look like a table? How many rows will the cursor query return - always one, or sometimes more (or zero)?

Comment: always one! i forgot to add group by in the question. I also don't get it but the task says: t must return a string of characters that contains the customer key, customer name, and the total number of orders made by each specified customer.@Alex Poole

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious? Concatenation result is longer than 1000 characters. Use larger local variable (e.g. `varchar2(30000)` or even a `CLOB`).

On the other hand, do you really need PL/SQL? How *long* result do you expect? If 4000 characters is enough, use `listagg`:

```
SQL> select listagg(ename ||'-'|| empno, ', ') within group (order by ename) result
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK-7782, KING-7839, MILLER-7934

SQL>
```

If it is longer than 4000 characters, use `xmlagg`:

```
SQL> select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, ename ||'-'|| empno ||', ') order by ename).extract('//text()'), ', ') result
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK-7782, KING-7839, MILLER-7934

SQL>
```

Both can be, of course, converted to a PL/SQL function, if you really need it.